# What is the significance of HRAAM beej mantra

Tags: scripture, vedas, mantras, bhagavata-purana, manuscripts

What is the significance of hraam beej mantra and which god or goddess is the beeja related to?

Comment: Beeja mantras are used to induce states of *samadhi*. The significance and nature of each are discovered using *Laya Yoga*. A beeja mantra doesn't necessarily need to be associated with any deity. All sects have their own intrepretation of association of each beeja mantra to their form of the deity. Usually the shakta intrepretation is widely accepted as it covers most of the beeja mantras.