# What is the meaning of namaha in mantra

Tags: scripture, mantras, manuscripts, mantra-diksha

I want to meditate on the meaning of a mantra. And most mantras consist of namaha at the end. I have heard it means “I bow down to”. Is it the accurate meaning that I should meditate upon or does namaha has any other true meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are concerned about Mantrartha without knowing which a Japa is futile.

See the following verse where Lord Shiva says:

> mantrArtham mantra chaitanyam yonimudrAm na vetti yah |
>  shatakoti
> japenApi tasya siddhirna jAyate ||
>
> One who chants mantras without knowing MantrArtha, Mantrachaitanya and
> YonimudrA, does not get Siddhi even after crores of chants.
>
> *KulArnava Tantram 15.60*

On this verse, the Commentator (Upendra Kumar Das) explains the term Mantrartha thus:

> MantrArtha - The existence of non-difference among the Guru, the deity
> and the mantra is called MantrArtha.

So, when it is said that Mantrartha should be aware of while chanting implies that the aspirant, while doing the Japa,should fix his mind on the the non-difference of the three entities :- Deity,Mantra and Guru.

It is not that one has to meditate on the meaning of the Mantra itself.

For example,for Sri Krishna there is a Mantra "Om Klim Gopi Jana Vallabhaya Swaha". Now it is well known that Swaha is the consort of Agni Deva. Now, while chanting this mantra if someone meditates on Swaha, the wife of Agni, that will be incorrect.

Having said that, Namah definitely has a meaning and it can be understood from the following:

> The oblations should be offered on Kusha blades spread out on the
> ground ; and the one, well-versed in the Sastras should first offer
> three oblations by prefixing Om and appending Namas to the Mantra as
> follows :
>
> Om, to Vishvadevas **(Namas) obeisance** ; Om, to all the beings
> (Bhutas) Namas (obeisance); Om, to the lord of all the beings (Butandm
> Patayae) Namas (obeisance) ; and after that, Om, to Pitris (obeisance)
> Namas. (31 32)
>
> **Vyasa Smriti Ch 3 verses**

Thus it is easy to see that Namah or Namas means obeisance.

In the Tantras it is also known as the Hrit (heart) mantra. Often it is used as a substitute for Om (Uninitiates can not chant Om in an application but in that place they can chant Namah).

The Smritis also approve the use of Namah by the Sudras in rituals. I have checked Varada Tantram verses if they have further explanation of the mantra Namah but could not find any. So from the standpoint of meditating on the visual form of Namah I could not find anything.

Comment: Please explain the meaning of namaha. I already have understood the meaning of my mantra. But I still want to know about the word namaha if it adds furthermore meaning. @rickross

Comment: Yes, I will try to update as soon as possible @Santhosh

Comment: See the update @Santhosh

Comment: Thank you so much for this info @Rickross

Comment: No problem @Santhosh

Comment: Can you answer my other question here @Rickross  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/56841/what-is-the-significance-of-hraam-beej-mantra

Comment: I have done a preliminary search on this Bija but could not find it in Varada Tantram. Will have to search more.  I think I have seen this Bija used during Anga Nyasa of some deity's japa @Santhosh

Comment: It's used in popular Surya mantra and other deities. I would be grateful if you can find any details related to the bija. I have been searching forever @Rickross

Comment: I will search and try to answer @Santhosh

Comment: Thanks. Will be waiting. I have been searching everywhere but couldn't find a exact name and meaning of this bija @Rickross